# Ошибка SQL: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Я изучаю SQL и не до конца понимаю, что делаю в этом коде. Мне кажется, что я пытаюсь создать сущность `DimaLaptop` от класса `Laptop`. Поле класса `DimaLaptop.screen` при помощи оператора `INNER JOIN`, я пытаюсь **определить как** значение поля `OlgaLaptop.screen` . Однако, здесь SQL возвращает ошибку:

> The multi-part identifier "DimaLaptop.screen" could not be bound.

Я использую такой SQL запрос. Он выглядит странно, потому что записан не до конца.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductCheck.maker, ProductCheck.model

FROM 
     Laptop as DimaLaptop, 
     Product as MishaDevice
-- Размер экрана Диминого Laptop на 3 больше Олиного

INNER JOIN Laptop as OlgaLaptop
    ON OlgaLaptop.screen + 3 = DimaLaptop.screen
-- Дима и Миша пользуются продуктами от одного производителя
```

Разумеется, никаких классов, сущностей и полей здесь нет - это не больше чем несколько таблиц, в которых я жонглирую ссылками на столбцы. Может быть, я "*определил*" объект класса `Laptop` `DimaLaptop` неправильно? Не могли бы вы указать мне на мою ошибку?

Comment: Ни при каких обстоятельствах не стоит смешивать в одном запросе явное (`TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON…`) и неявное (`TABLE1, TABLE2`) соединение!

Answer (score 1):

Везде говорят, что запятая (картезианское произведение таблиц) и CROSS JOIN - это одно и то же... а вот ни разу не так.

Да, по выполняемой функции похоже. Но различается приоритетом - запятая имеет приоритет меньше, чем все JOIN. И соответственно предложение

```sql
FROM 
     Laptop as DimaLaptop, 
     Product as MishaDevice
INNER JOIN Laptop as OlgaLaptop
```

с учётом приоритета эквивалентно

```sql
FROM Laptop as DimaLaptop
CROSS JOIN (            Product as MishaDevice
             INNER JOIN Laptop as OlgaLaptop )
```

Само собой, когда выполняется INNER JOIN, таблица `DimaLaptop`, которая за скобками, ещё не принимает участия в формировании источника данных, не видна, и попытка использовать её поля приводит к тому, что `The multi-part identifier "DimaLaptop.screen" could not be bound.`

---

Процитирую комментарий:

> Ни при каких обстоятельствах не стоит смешивать в одном запросе явное (`TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON…`) и неявное (`TABLE1, TABLE2`) соединение! – [Герман Борисов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183614/%d0%93%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%91%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

---

С учётом изложенного - замените запятую на CROSS JOIN, и проблема рассосётся сама собой.